# SortedSet in Silverlight: looking for a memory- and time-efficient implementation

Tags: c#, silverlight, collections, sortedset

I am looking for a memory and performance efficient implementation of SortedSet<T> (corresponding to System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T> in vanilla .NET).

For the time being, I have taken a very simplistic approach, implementing the ISet<T> interface and internally storing the items in a List<T> that I re-sort after every data inclusion:

```
public class SortedSet<T> : ISet<T>
{
    private List<T> _collection; 
    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;
    ...
}
```

I have taken a look at the Mono source code for [SortedSet](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Generic/SortedSet.cs), but as far as I can tell this implementation is not easily portable to Silverlight. There is also the [SortedArray](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/arrays/SortedArray.cs) class in the C5 generic collection class library that I believe is applicable to Silverlight, but then I would probably need to include the entire [C5 library](https://github.com/sestoft/C5). I would prefer a more light-weight solution.

Does anyone have any recommendations of a light-weight, fast and memory efficient open-source SortedSet<T> implementation applicable to Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your `SortedSet<T>` to internally use the [Mono implementation of `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Generic/SortedList.cs). At first glance, this has not so much dependencies to other Mono code as `SortedSet<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Daniel. However, I am not interested in a key-value solution, I only want a collection of distinct items, sorted using the default or a user-provided comparer. If you look at HashSet<T>, it provides the functionality I am after, except for the sorting.

Comment: @Anders: You can easily implement your requirement using a `SortedList`. Simply insert your item as the key and `null` as the value.

Comment: OK, Daniel, I see what you mean. However, this does not sound very efficient from a memory or performance point-of-view, or?

Comment: @Anders: Performance-wise this shouldn't make a difference, because the `SortedList` is sorted by the key only. The memory footprint will be a bit higher, because you need to safe two references instead of one per item but this shouldn't be a problem if you don't put millions of items into the list. A short calculation: Size of a reference: 4 byte. Additional memory consumption if you put 100.000 items into the list: about 390 KB